# Directory.EnumerateFiles with Take and Where

Tags: vb.net

I have following Problem:

```
For Each _file As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Quellpfad, "*.rdy").Take(500).Where(Function(item) item.Replace(Quellpfad, "").Length <= 11)
```

this code should take files from a Directory saved in the String "Quellpfad" 
by These 2 criteria:

1.) only 500 files

2.) filename lenth <= 11 eg.: 0330829.rdy

The file 0330829.rdy is in the Directory but I can't find it with the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder your statement to put the `Where` before the `Take`:

```
For Each _file As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Quellpfad, "*.rdy").Where(Function(item) item.Replace(Quellpfad, "").Length <= 11).Take(500)
```

The `Where` returns all files matching your condition FIRST, and THEN limits those down to 500.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Take` last because you want to apply the filter first, you should also use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) or `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` instead of `String.Replace`:

```
Dim files = From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Quellpfad, "*.rdy")
            Where Path.GetFileName(file).Length <= 11
            Take 500
```

In VB.NET query syntax supports `Take`, so i'd prefer that.